# Как вызвать js функцию на стороннем сайте?

Tags: javascript

есть страничка на одном сайте, есть тег:
    <a class="qwerty" onclick="myfunction(1000,12345,1)">

функция отправляет запрос на их серв, какой то скрипт отрабатывает и возвр. результат, как вызвать эту функцию со своими параметрами использую постоянно разный ip, например юзая Tor?

Comment: Поковыряйте исходный код сайта =)

Кстати, JS не отправляет данные на сервер!

Comment: @Asen Как это JS не отправляет данные? А AJAX?

Comment: Но здесь же нет метки AJAX =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Откройте `Firebug` или `Chrome dev tools` на вкладке Network, чтобы посмотреть, по какому URL эта функция общается с сервером (какие параметры передает и прочее). Разобравшись, можете использовать ее на своем компьютере с плавающим IP, используя `curl` или подобную тулзу в скрипте, подставляя нужные параметры.

IP тут, в принципе, не важен (если, разумеется, на сайте не проверяется его значение). А вот заголовок `referer` может иметь значение. Но `curl`, если не изменяет память, позволяет его устанавливать.

НО! Вызвать эту функцию с другими параметрами на своем сайте не получится, ибо [same origin policy](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0). Впрочем, есть способы его обхода, посмотрите [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy) и выбирите подходящий. Опять же, если удаленным сайтом учитывается значение `referer`, ничего не выйдет - подменить его средствами JS не представляется возможным.